# Is Hot Spot analysis appropriate if you see hot spots in areas that you would expect to see them in?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, density, hot-spot

I am working with vessel position data on ArcGIS 10.0. My customer has requested density analysis maps. I was curious if hot spot analysis would be a more appropriate analysis? The study area is along a coastline of a country, and of course, there are going to be hot spots in choke points (port areas). Would hot spot analysis really show us any statistically significant areas that we wouldn't normally see? I understand that this completely depends on the dispersal of the data and it certainly would if you see an area that you wouldn't think to be a hot spot but was. I am having a hard time ensuring I am on the right track here instead of just providing a density map which everyone seems to want but that is entirely subjective.

Comment: Please tell us what your customer is trying to learn about vessel routes.  Only then could we suggest appropriate analytical techniques.

Comment: Well specifically they are trying to figure out areas where there may be an increased need for search and rescue support operations, based off known vessel positions